# Extending python log hander, getting "Level not an integer or a valid string"

Tags: python, django, logging, extend

I am trying to create my own log handler, which extends logging.Handler

```
import logging
from logging import Handler

class DBHandler(Handler,object):
    model = None
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(DBHandler, self).__init__(self)
        mod = __import__(model)
        components = name.split('.')
        for comp in components[1:]:
            mod = getattr(mod, comp)
        self.model = mod

    def emit(self,record):
        log_entry = self.model(level=record.levelname, message=record.msg)
        log_entry.save()
```

and this is the log config:

```
'search_log':{
    'level': 'INFO',
    'class': 'logger.handlers.DBHandler',
    'model': 'logger.models.SearchLog',
    'formatter': 'verbose',
     }
```

however I am getting the follow error, see stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/james/virtualenv/hydrogen/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'search_log': Level not an integer or a valid string: <logger.handlers.DBHandler object at 0x2df1710>
```

I have been looking at the python logging source code and cannot figure out what I have done wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
super(DBHandler, self).__init__(self)
```

You should not be passing `self` in if you use `super` this way. You're passing in `self` twice, effectively, and the `logging` module is trying to interpret the 2nd `self` as a logging level.

Comment: NP: easy question, easy answer. But would you mind accepting it as the correct answer?

Comment: another quick question, I now keep getting "'module' object has no attribute 'handlers'" any ideas?

Comment: Is there a traceback, and does it say `logging.handlers` somewhere in it? It might be easier to post as a separate question so you can post the traceback and details.

Comment: Where is `logger.handlers.DBHandler` defined?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452904/extending-python-logger-unable-to-import-custom-handler

Answer (score 0):

i solved the same problem with changing the level='Debug' to level=30
python 3.9.0

"Level not an integer or a valid string:'%r%' level